# Using SelectionChangeCommited with combobox in c#

Tags: c#, combobox

I have this combobox which items is manually added as:

```
    public void bindCB_showclientBy()
    {
        cb_selectclientBy.Items.Add("address");
        cb_selectclientBy.Items.Add("field");

        cb_selectclientBy.ValueMember = "field";
        cb_selectclientBy.DisplayMember = "field";
    }
```

Now i am using the `selectionChangeComitted` for this combobox but it wont work even when i select item in combobox.

```
Protected void cb_selectclientBy_SelectionChangeCommitted( object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (cb_selectclientBy.SelectedValue != null)
            {
                string st = cb_selectclientBy.SelectedValue.ToString();
            }
        }
```

What am i missing?

**EDIT**
The event handling is done.When i select the item it goes to the selectionchangecommited but fails in the `if` condition.

Answer (score 0):

You need to hook up your event handler. Where you are creating your combo box add the line

```
cb_selectclientBy.SelectionChangeCommitted += cb_selectclientBy_SelectionChangeCommitted
```

In that case try using `SelectedItem` instead of `SelectedValue` for more information see [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.combobox.selectionchangecommitted(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: No matter which one i use, the problem is same dosent go past `if`.